# Why is setTimeout shows up in stack trace of error thrown into its callback

Tags: javascript

Consider following code:

```
setTimeout(()=>{
    throw new Error("Testing error");
},100)
```

I ran this code in chrome console I got this:

```
Uncaught Error: Testing error
at setTimeout (<anonymous>:2:15)
```

But I wasn't expecting to see `setTimeout` there. This is because `setTimeout` has already been removed from callstack 100ms before its callback was run on call stack.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: setTimeout callback is basically using a Closure, so the callback can still access its previous environment. That's the reason the setTimeout is still visible. Can someone else also confirm if I am right!?

Comment: I also believe closure is the reason...
I've read a good article a few days ago, I hope it will of good use to you @dasfdsa

https://blog.bitsrc.io/a-beginners-guide-to-closures-in-javascript-97d372284dda

Comment: I am not sure how closure fits here. IMO, unless callback has some variables referenced, which were declared in outer scope, outer scope variables are eligible for garbage collection. So in this case, setTimeout might already been GCed. I might be wrong though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I wasn't expecting to see `setTimeout` there. This is because `setTimeout` has already been removed from callstack 100ms before its callback was run on call stack.

Correct, it's not on the call stack.

> Can someone explain this?

Chrome is just trying to be helpful here. It derives a name for the anonymous arrow function - from the line where it was created. Inspect the whole call stack (by clicking on the expand arrow):

```
setTimeout @ VM4560:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ VM4560:1
```

The italic `setTimeout (async)` (and everything below) comes from [asynchronous stack traces](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/05/devtools-release-notes#async-stacks). It does indeed remember from where the callback that threw the exception was scheduled: with `setTimeout`, from the console context.

Let's instead try

```
function example(cb) {
    setTimeout(cb, 100);
}
example(() => {
    throw new Error("Testing error");
});
```

and we will get

```
example    @   VM4562:5
setTimeout (async)
example @   VM4562:2
(anonymous) @   VM4562:4
```

Again, the callback is named after the function it was passed to - `example` in this case. The original `example()` call can be found in the async stack trace.

We could use a named function expression instead to clarify:

```
setTimeout(function callback() {
    throw new Error("Testing error");
}, 100);
```

Now we get the expected

```
callback @ VM4564:2
setTimeout (async)
(anonymous) @ VM4564:1
```

Answer (score 0):

> This is because setTimeout has already been removed from callstack 100ms before its callback was run on call stack

This is going back to how `setTimout()` work.

As we all know javascipt is a single threaded programming language, this tells us that
`setTimout()` is not a part of JS or (v8) the javascript runtime, But it is part of the webapi provided by the browser.

Now when we call `setTimout()` it get's pushed to the stack what is does is takes the callback you provided push it to the webapi then it gets removed from the stack, now the webapi is the one doing all the waiting because it is another thread provided by the browser.

Wen the delay is done the callback gets pushed to the stack queue then the event loops kicks in, what the even loop does is keep waiting for the stack to be emptied and then it starts dequeuing queue stack and push it back to the stack.

So what you're seeing is totally normal it just doesn't seem right.

Comment: This explains how setTimeout works. But doesn't attempt to answer the question. Thanks for your post, in any case.