# Why is the call stack not empty before executing the function in Task Queue?

Tags: javascript

```
function first() {
    function second() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            console.log('hello') /*break point here on chrome dev*/
        }, 1000);
    }
    second()
}
first();
```

Per my understanding of Event Loop:

1. Look at the call stack and task queue
2. If the call stack is empty then take the first thing on the task queue and push on the call stack and the stack runs it.

My question is: why the call stack is:

```
------------------
(anonymous)
setTimeout (async)
-----------------
second
-----------------
first
-----------------
(anonymous)
-----------------
```

instead of:

```
-----------------
(anonymous) [callback Fn passed in setTimeout] 
-----------------
```

Based on the Event Loop (see #2 definition), the first and second execution context should have been already popped up off the call stack before executing the callback function in setTimeout.

Comment: that's the call stack, not the event loop queue - you'd need the call stack, for closures? right?

Comment: We don't have any closures here-- the inner functions second() and setTimout(function(){..}) are not using any variables from the outer function, i.e first(). Yes this is call stack as mentioned.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52682763/why-is-settimeout-shows-up-in-stack-trace-of-error-thrown-into-its-callback

Answer (score 4):

You see this trace because your dev-tools are configured to keep the async calls trace.

See [this doc](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13Sy_kBIJGP0XT34V1CV3nkWya4TwYx9L3Yv45LdGB6Q/edit) for few details.

You can disable this by typing `Do not capture async stack trace` in the "Run command" menu (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> from your dev-tools).

The real stack is indeed empty before the event loop picks the next async task.

Comment: The real call stack isn't empty, but it starts above the frame that is marked as `(async)`. There is only the `(anonymous)` on the stack when hitting the breakpoint on the `console.log`.

Comment: @Bergi I meant to say it is empty before the event loop picks the next async task, as per OP's understanding

Comment: This was helpful. Now I see only (anonymous) in the  call stack as expected.